# Representation of 1 + 2.0^-24

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

Im trying to figure why the number `1 + 2.0^-24` in single arithmetic precision is stored as `1.0` instead of `1 + 2^-23` since we can check that `1 + 2.0^-24 - 1 + 2^-23 = 2^-24` and `1.0 + 2.0^-24 - 1.0 = 2^-24` and `1.0 and 1.0 + 2^-23` are two closet numbers to `1.0+2^-24`. Why is the computer choosing `1.0` ?

Comment: Thats very dependant. What data type does the variable you store it in have?

Comment: It is based on your rounding principle

Comment: The programming language, data type, compiler, and processor type (64 vs 32 bit) may all have an influence on how data is actually stored, as far as I know.